# Dates from a text file

Tags: java

I just wanted to ask whether it is possible to find Dates in all possible formats in a text file and print the results. I was able to open the file and format the dates but I couldn't combine the two elements. Here are the codes so far.
I appreciate any help.Thanks

here are the requirements and my approach :

Code needs to search all headings, headers, text and footnotes.
 Code searches for a date, such as day of week, month, numeral 1 to 31 followed by a month, year between 1950 & 2050.
Code needs to get date as well as the nearest heading above and get the applicable main section 
 Code needs to get page number.

For Date :

```
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Dates
{
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
 Date d1 = new Date();
 DateFormat[] dfa = new DateFormat[6];
 dfa[0] = DateFormat.getInstance();
 dfa[1] = DateFormat.getDateInstance();
 dfa[2] = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT);
 dfa[3] = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM);
 dfa[4] = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.LONG);
 dfa[5] = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.FULL);

 for(DateFormat df : dfa)
 {
 System.out.println(df.format(d1));


 }
 DateFormat df2 = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.FULL);
 String s = df2.format(d1);
 System.out.println(s);

 try
 {
 Date d2 = df2.parse(s);
 System.out.println("parsed = " +d2.toString());

 }
 catch(ParseException pe)
 {
 System.out.println("Parse Exception");
 }
 }
}
```

for opening files :

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class FileOpener {
 /**
 * use a dialog box to select a text file (.txt)
 * @return a Scanner for the selected file, or null if cancel selected
 */

 public static Scanner selectTextFile() {
 do {
 JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
 FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter(
 "Text/Java files","doc", "txt", "java");
 chooser.setFileFilter(filter);
 int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
 try {
 if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
 return new Scanner(chooser.getSelectedFile());
 } 
 else {
 return null;
 }
 }
 catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid file!",
 "error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE); 
 }
 } while (true);
 }
 /**
 * given a String, uses a Scanner to count the number of words
 * @return number of words in the String
 */
 public static int countWordsOnLine(String line) {
 Scanner s = new Scanner(line);
   //int count = 0;
 while (s.hasNext()) {
 s.next();
  //count++;
 }
  //return count;
 }
 public static void main(String[] args) {
 // make Java look like your normal OS

 try {
 UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
 }
 catch (Exception e) { // ignore exceptions and continue
 }
 Scanner lineScanner = FileOpener.selectTextFile();
 int numberOfWords = 0;
 if (lineScanner!=null) {
 while (lineScanner.hasNextLine()) {
 numberOfWords += FileOpener.countWordsOnLine(
 lineScanner.nextLine());
 }
 System.out.println("The number of words is: " + numberOfWords);
 //System.out.println(getPageNumber());
 }
 }
}
```

Table that will contain the end result:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
 import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

public class SimpleTableDemo extends JPanel {
 private boolean DEBUG = false;

 public SimpleTableDemo() {
 super(new GridLayout(1,0));

 String[] columnNames = {"HEADER",
 "SENTENCE",
 "PAGE",
 "DATE"};

 Object[][] data = {
 {" ", " ",
 " ", new Integer(5)},
 {" ", " ",
 " ", new Integer(3)},
 {" ", " ",
 " ", new Integer(2)},
 {" ", " ",
 " ", new Integer(20)},
 {" ", " ",
 " ", new Integer(10)}
 };

 final JTable table = new JTable(data, columnNames);
 table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(500, 70));
 table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);

 if (DEBUG) {
 table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
 public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
 printDebugData(table);
 }
 });
 }

 //Create the scroll pane and add the table to it.
 JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);

 //Add the scroll pane to this panel.
 add(scrollPane);
 }

 private void printDebugData(JTable table) {
 int numRows = table.getRowCount();
 int numCols = table.getColumnCount();
 javax.swing.table.TableModel model = table.getModel();

 System.out.println("Value of data: ");
 for (int i=0; i < numRows; i++) {
 System.out.print(" row " + i + ":");
 for (int j=0; j < numCols; j++) {
 System.out.print(" " + model.getValueAt(i, j));
 }
 System.out.println();
 }
 System.out.println("--------------------------");
 }

 /**
 * Create the GUI and show it. For thread safety,
 * this method should be invoked from the
 * event-dispatching thread.
 */
 private static void createAndShowGUI() {
 //Create and set up the window.
 JFrame frame = new JFrame("SimpleTableDemo");
 frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

 //Create and set up the content pane.
 SimpleTableDemo newContentPane = new SimpleTableDemo();
 newContentPane.setOpaque(true); //content panes must be opaque
 frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);

 //Display the window.
 frame.pack();
 frame.setVisible(true);
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) {
 //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
 //creating and showing this application's GUI.
 javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
 public void run() {
 createAndShowGUI();
 }
 });
 }
}
```

Comment: You might want to work on consistently indenting your code for (much) better readability.

Comment: Please limit your code to just the relevant portions, and ask a specific question.

Answer (score 1):

All dates is almost certainly impossible. How are you going to parse these?

- Second monday of March 2012
- Donderdag 14 oktober aanstaande.
- First sunday after the first full moon after the equinox of 2012

These are all dates, and many more possibilities are possible. You can write a script that will find most dates, but not all of them.

But your best strategy is probably to define a number of common patterns, and scan the text file line by line for them.